# Maya Python Toggle (Hotkey) command

Tags: python, maya

I have two lines of code as below:

## Hides all the curves not selected:

```
mel.eval('isolateAnimCurve true graphEditor1FromOutliner graphEditor1GraphEd;')
```

## Brings back all the curves:

```
mel.eval('isolateAnimCurve false graphEditor1FromOutliner graphEditor1GraphEd;')
```

Need a to put in a function (python) where it can be toggled, so I can use it as a hotkey in maya.

Answer (score 0):

```
def hideCurves():
    mel.eval('isolateAnimCurve true graphEditor1FromOutliner graphEditor1GraphEd;')

cmds.nameCommand( 'hideAllCurves', annotation='Hide Curves', command='python("hideCurves()")')
cmds.hotkey( k='F5', alt=True, name='hideAllCurves' )
```

This is pure python way, But I seriously doubt that you want to look into [hotkey editor](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-36D24C0F-19E4-411E-8CA9-DB7B64C3E6EA-htm.html)

Comment: can you explain what this line does, code by code: cmds.nameCommand( 'hideAllCurves', annotation='Hide Curves', command='python("hideCurves()")')

Comment: I am a newbie to this so trying to understand it step by step. The one thing I don't get at most is  what does comman='python("hideCurves()")') do?